# ui-router - How to load url without $stateParams on refresh?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My oversimplified app.config() has:

```
$stateProvider.
  state("/", {
  url: "/",
  templateUrl: "main.html"
}).
state("/newCategories", {
  url: "/categories/new",
  templateUrl: "/views/new_categories.html",
  controller: "newCategoriesCtrl"
}).
state("/categoryPages", {
url: "/categories/:address",
templateUrl: "/views/categories.html",
controller: "categoriesCtrl",
resolve: {
  categoriesDataResolve: function resolveTemplate($stateParams, DataResolver) {
    return DataResolver.resolveTemplates($stateParams.address);
  }
}
});
```

With this I can use **ui-serf** link with "/newCategories" to load its url: "/categories/new"

```
<a ui-sref="/newCategories">New Category</a>
```

However, when I refresh, it thinks that "/new" is part of $stateParams. Therefore it uses a different controller and tries to resolve its template (which is missing, so it gives an error).

For now I fixed it by changing the url from "/categories/new" to "/categories-new" so it won't get confused on refresh. **But how do I solve this issue differently?** (Maybe ui-router has a some way of dealing with it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, you want to call different controller a.e. `newCategoriesCtrl` when user calls `/categories/:address` where `address` param is `new`

Changing `/categories/new` to `"/categories-new` is a right way to solve it.

---

Small tip: its not good practice to use `/` as prefix for state name. It confuses the developer and can be mixed with original URL.

```
$stateProvider.
//...
state("newCategories", {
  url: "/categories-new",
  templateUrl: "/views/new_categories.html",
  controller: "newCategoriesCtrl"
}).
state("categoryPages", {
  url: "/categories/:address",
  templateUrl: "/views/categories.html",
  controller: "categoriesCtrl",
  resolve: {
   //...
  }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to somehow check for reserved links (like "new" or "edit") and change controllers accordingly? Or is it a bad practice?

Comment: @AlekseySolovey well, every state has own controller. Im sure you don't want to create nested controllers :)